# Images not uploaded on ebay via ebay API

Tags: ebay-lms

We are using ebay API and upload images on Ebay server using **UploadSiteHostedPicture** API.

The image request which are sending is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
  <BulkDataExchangeRequests>  
    <Header>
      <SiteID>0</SiteID>  
      <Version>863</Version>  
    </Header>  
    <UploadSiteHostedPicturesRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">  
      <ErrorLanguage>en_US</ErrorLanguage>  
       <WarningLevel>High</WarningLevel>
    <Version>863</Version>
    <MessageID>Request0</MessageID>
    <ExternalPictureURL><![CDATA[MyImageUrl1]]>
    </ExternalPictureURL>
</UploadSiteHostedPicturesRequest>
<UploadSiteHostedPicturesRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <ErrorLanguage>en_US</ErrorLanguage>
    <WarningLevel>High</WarningLevel>
    <Version>863</Version>
    <MessageID>Request1</MessageID>
    <ExternalPictureURL><![CDATA[MyImageUrl2]]>
    </ExternalPictureURL>
</UploadSiteHostedPicturesRequest>  
</BulkDataExchangeRequests>
```

We have also checked that image urls are correct and no issue with Images. But Every time we are getting error response as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<BulkDataExchangeResponses xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents"  
  <UploadSiteHostedPicturesResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents  
   <Timestamp>2014-05-23T08:09:55.778Z</Timestamp>  
   <Ack>Failure</Ack>  
   <CorrelationID>Request0</CorrelationID>  
   <Errors>  
     <ShortMessage>There was a Picture Services server problem or there is a problem with your picture file.</ShortMessage>  
     <LongMessage>There was a Picture Services server problem or there is a problem with your picture file. Please try again later and if the problem persists, then try again using a different picture file.</LongMessage>  
     <ErrorCode>21917241</ErrorCode>  
     <SeverityCode>Error</SeverityCode  
     <ErrorClassification>RequestError</ErrorClassification>  
   </Errors>  
   <Version>857</Version>  
   <Build>E857_CORE_MSA_16683676_R1</Build>  
</UploadSiteHostedPicturesResponse>  
<UploadSiteHostedPicturesResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents  
   <Timestamp>2014-05-23T08:09:55.778Z</Timestamp>  
   <Ack>Failure</Ack>  
   <CorrelationID>Request0</CorrelationID>  
   <Errors>  
     <ShortMessage>There was a Picture Services server problem or there is a problem with your picture file.</ShortMessage>  
     <LongMessage>There was a Picture Services server problem or there is a problem with your picture file. Please try again later and if the problem persists, then try again using a different picture file.</LongMessage>  
     <ErrorCode>21917241</ErrorCode>  
     <SeverityCode>Error</SeverityCode  
     <ErrorClassification>RequestError</ErrorClassification>  
   </Errors>  
   <Version>857</Version>  
   <Build>E857_CORE_MSA_16683676_R1</Build>  
</UploadSiteHostedPicturesResponse>  
</BulkDataExchangeResponses>
```

We have also searched solutions for this but nothing got. Can you please tell me the reason why we are getting this error? or what is the solution for this issue.

We have also tried to contact to ebay and their developer support, but no link or contact found through which we can contact to ebay and find solution for our problem.
Do anyone know that how can we contact to ebay developer support and contact to ebay?

Waiting for solution but we would like prefer to know about how can we contact to ebay?.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the image URL that you are feeding into eBay is not https, eBay only accepts http urls.